# AWS Glue Job using awsglueml.transforms.FindMatches gives timeout error seemingly randomly

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a Glue ETL Job (using pyspark) that gives a timeout error when trying to access the awsglueml.transforms.FindMatches library seemingly randomly. The error given on the glue dashboard is:

```
An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.ml.FindMatches.apply. The target server failed to respond
```

Basically if I try to run this Glue ETL job late at night, it most of the time succeeds. But if I try to run this ETL Job in the middle of the day, it fails with this error.  Sometimes just retrying it enough times causes it to succeed, but this doesn't seem like a good solution. It seems like the issue is with AWS FindMatches library not having enough bandwidth to support people wanting to use this library, but I could be wrong here.

The Glue ETL job was setup using the option [A proposed script generated by AWS Glue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY7CW.png)

The line of code that this is timing out on is a line that was provided by glue when I created this job:

```
from awsglueml.transforms import FindMatches
...

findmatches2 = FindMatches.apply(frame = datasource0, transformId = "<redacted>", computeMatchConfidenceScores = True, transformation_ctx = "findmatches2")
```

Welcoming any information on this elusive issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by including this configuration in the glue job:

```
--conf="spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum=5000"
```